# What is the maximal number of such vectors?

Tags: combinatorics, vectors

$n,k$ are integers and I need to find the maximal integer $M$ such that there exist $M$ different n-dimensional vectors whose components are in $\{-1,1\}$ satisfying: any two of $M$ vectors has exactly $k$ different components.

For example if $n=4$, $k=1$ $M$ will be $2$ because we can assume $X_1=(1,1,1,1)$ then $X_2$ has one component $-1$, others are $1$,for example $X_2=(-1,1,1,1)$. However, different $X_3$ can not be found because any new $X_3$ should also has only one $-1$ component but different from $X_2$, which will make $X_2,X_3$ have $2$ different components.

I tried but find it difficult to find the formula, A good upper boundary will also be helpful as I think at least induction can be used.

Comment: You may consider the case where any two of M vectors have no less than $k$ different components, which corresponds to the concept of minimum distance in code theory. This case would provide an upper bound. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/codingtheory/notes/notes4.pdf

Comment: Oh,thank you. It helps a lot.